# Read lines from .txt and store into different integers

Tags: java

So i got the following code:

```
    BufferedReader ind = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Billet_priser.txt"));
    String line = ind.readLine();
    String[] bits = line.split(" "); // opdel i bidder efter mellemrum

    line = ind.readLine();
    bits = line.split(" ");
    Ticket1 = Integer.parseInt(bits[1]);
    line = ind.readLine();
    line.split(" ");
    Ticket2 = Integer.parseInt(bits[1]);
    line = ind.readLine();
    line.split(" ");
    ...
    line = ind.readLine();
    line.split(" ");
    Ticketn = Integer.parseInt(bits[1]);
}
```

reading from the .txt file with the following text:

```
Ticket1 99
Ticket2 35
...
Ticketn 60
```

Trying to get the second bit after a space in each line to be stored in the ticket integers.

The problem is that it only stores the first read int "99" into all the ticket integers.
I want it to read the next line after storing the first int into the first ticket, then read the next line and so on.

Comment: you should split every line you read, you're splitting only first one, also - take a look on how to use loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is a bit off. You want to make a container of tickets and use the loop to fill it.

```
List<Integer> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader ind = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Billet_priser.txt")){
    String line = null;
    while ((line = ind.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] bits = line.split(" ");     
        tickets.add(Integer.parseInt(bits[1]));
    }
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You keep using this `bits` value to get the number:

```
Ticket1 = Integer.parseInt(bits[1]);
```

But you only ever set it *once* from the first line:

```
String[] bits = line.split(" ");     
while (line != null) {
    // bits is never updated in here
}
```

It sounds like you want to simply repeat that line of code to update the `bits` variable:

```
line = ind.readLine();
bits = line.split(" ");
Ticket1 = Integer.parseInt(bits[1]);
```

(Note also that your loop doesn't make much sense, because it looks like you're *manually* reading every line with repeated lines of code instead of actually looping.  The three lines of code above, or whatever constitutes one iteration of your loop, should only have to exist once.  Loops are designed to repeat that task over and over.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) object instead of BufferedReader. Construct it like this:

```
Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(new File("Billet_priser.txt");
```

Then fix your `while` loop to do something more like this:

```
while (scannerObject.hasNextLine()){
    String[] line = scannerObject.nextLine().split(" ");
    int currentTicket = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
}
```

You could also store the ticket numbers in an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) constructed like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then your `while` loop would look like this:

```
while (scannerObject.hasNextLine()){
    String[] line = scannerObject.nextLine().split(" ");
    tickets.add(Integer.parseInt(line[1]));
}
```